# Extracting In-App Message Analytics data in journey builder for individual contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios

We would like to track for individual contacts the following data:

- Was the message displayed or not?
- What buttons were clicked within the message.

We can see this info when clicking on a in-app activity within a journey and going to the analytics tab. However it is displayed there as a summary and not per contact as we would like.

[image: Analytics tab in journey builder]

**Is there any data view or other way to extract the data displayed in the analytics tab and build a DE accordingly? If not - is there other known soultion to achieve this (via SDK and API requests from the app maybe?).**

Notice we found this report: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_mp_run_the_mobilepush_detail_extract_report.htm&type=5

However we discovered the "MessageOpened" field in this report does not get populated for in-app message and there is no data regarding buttons clicks in the message as well.

Thanks,

Barak

Answer (score 2):

We're hoping to add granular contact-level data into an extract in an upcoming release. Until then, you can see aggregated data in the UI or by running a report in the Reports app within Marketing Cloud (Analytics Builder).